# A question on complex conjugate

Tags: polynomials, complex-numbers

I'm trying to solve this problem appeared in a questionnaire of an engineering student. I think it is not difficult but I cannot solve it on the first try.

Find all complex values of the constant m for which there is a polynomial $P (z)$, $P\ne 0$, satisfying for all $z$ the condition $P(z)=m\overline{(P(\bar z)}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

a) In your condition, replace $z$ by $\overline{z}$ and take the conjugate to see a necessary condition on $m$.

b) Use $P(z)=cz$ to see that the condition found is sufficient. ( And using the remark by Shahar Even-Dar-Mandel, you can take simply $P(z)=c$ for a non zero constant $c$.)

Comment: Actually, you don't even have to take $P(z)=cz$, even $P(z)=c$ is a non-zero polynomial in $z$.

Comment: @Shahar Even-Dar-Mandel : You are true, I have edited my answer.